# Using SQL join to sort elements of the same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I'm a novice MySQL programmer, and I am trying to create a simple website with users that can send messages between each other.

The messages are stored in one table called `message`, with a date, from user, to users, text, subject, and index. The index is the primary key, but I want to sort it by the `tou` (to users) section.

I was wondering if I could use the SQL `JOIN` syntax within one table to sort it. I'll loop through all the messages and run this query every time to find matches:

```
SELECT message.text
FROM message
LEFT JOIN message
ON message.tou = [this one's to users]
```

I'm not a very advanced programmer, and I'm unfamiliar with the `JOIN` syntax, so please advise me on how to use this the way I want to, if possible. I know there are a lot of questions like this out there, so if there's one that solves my question, please redirect me to it, too.

Also tell me if I'm unclear.

I'm trying to get the following output:

If `message` has the following rows:

```
INDEX | TOU        | FROMU | TEXT
1     | u1, u2     | u4    | hello from u4
2     | u1, u3     | u3    | hello from u3
3     | u1, u2     | u5    | hello from u5
        ^ organize this row
```

I want it to organize it so that it arranges it like so:

```
TOU    | TEXT
u1, u2 | hello from u4
       | hello from u5
u1,u3  | hello from u3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have some example input and output to work with?

Comment: Sorting is normally done using the `ORDER BY` clause. You don't need a `JOIN` unless you need to match data between tables or subqueries. But maybe the problem is that you're not describing what you want very well. Please show some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: @Barmar I want to put the ones with the same `tou` results together, rather than use `ORDER BY` and list them separated. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry to put it this way, but you've done things the wrong way. You have a column with multiple values. That only generates trouble. If a message can be sent to N users then you should have a separate table to identify to whom each message has been sent to.EG: `(MessageID, ToUser)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does it.

```
SELECT tou, text
FROM (
    SELECT IF(tou = @lasttou, '', tou) tou, text, @lasttou := tou
    FROM (SELECT tou, text
          FROM message
          ORDER by tou) message,
         (SELECT @lasttou := NULL) vars
) x
```

`ORDER BY` gets the rows in the order you want. Then it uses `@lasttou` to keep from displaying the same `tou` value when it's repeated across rows.

In practice, I would implement this duplicate suppression in an application language that's being used for the user interface, not in SQL.

[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf386/1)

Comment: Subqueries need to have names assigned to them. These are arbitrary names.